# Как скомпилировать на более ранней версии java в IDE

Tags: java

Есть 32 битные машины windows 7. Eclipse создает jar файл на 15 версии jdk. Ее не установишь на 32 битные машины. Думаю скомпилировать jar на более ранней версии jdk. Как это сделать в IDE? Либо какое то другое решение. Спасибо.

Comment: скачайте jdk 1.8, в настройках проекта укажите путь к jdk или можете указать переменные среды такие как JAVA_HOME

Comment: Спасибо. Переменную среды указал. Но думаю можно было и не указывать. В eclipse при создании проекта поставил галочку в блоке JRE использовать JRE по умолчанию. И там же выбрал компилятор 1.8. Еще в window - preferences указал путь к jdk 1.8 .

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Переменную среды указал. Но думаю можно было и не указывать. В eclipse при создании проекта поставил галочку в блоке JRE использовать JRE по умолчанию. И там же выбрал компилятор 1.8. Еще в window - preferences указал путь к jdk 1.8